# Paid charts are not shown in the PDF

Tags: charts, image-charts

we have a doubt regarding your platform. We use it to generate graphics in the pdf of our platform. Everything was perfect with the free graphics, however with the payments (white mark), we observed that these are not shown in the pdf.[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said earlier through our support, the URL encoding might be the issue and triggers an invalid HMAC signature error :)

Comment: effectively, by entering the url in the src of the img tag for each "&", "amp;" was added. I could already resolve, thanks for your response.